# JQuery function called, not executing and no errors in dev console

Tags: javascript, jquery

My page has a series of buttons with onclick events to call a jQuery function called ShowCenter() that populates a div with content.  This has worked for a long time:

```
<div class="C1"><button class="button_01" id="first" onclick="ShowCenter(1); ShowFarRight(150);">Button Text Here</button></div>
```

Today I added a new `function ShowFarRight()` to populate another div immediately after the first function is called:

```
<script>
function ShowFarRight(type) {
  console.log("Far Right-1");
  $(" #C3 ").empty();
  $(" #C3 ").scrollTop();
  var filename = "text_" + type + ".htm"
  $( "#C3" ).hide().load( filename ).fadeIn(500);
  console.log("Far Right-2");  }
</script>
```

The problem is that `ShowFarRight` doesn't do anything and the the Firefox and Chrome dev consoles don't show the console.log messages or any other errors.

EDIT:  here is the code for ShowCenter

```
<script>
var CurrentPageLoad
function ShowCenter(type) {
    $(" #C2 ").empty();
    $(" #C2 ").scrollTop();
    var filename = "text_" + type + ".htm"
    $( "#C2" ).hide().load( filename ).fadeIn(500);
    CurrentPageLoad = type;
    console.log("CPL " + CurrentPageLoad);
}
</script>
```

That console.log does show.

Comment: `$(" #C3 ")` is not the same as `$( "#C3" )`. Would you like to change it to `$(" #C3 ")` and see?

Comment: @PraveenKumarPurushothaman OP doesn't see output `console.log`. Maybe it's not allowed to call several function on click?

Comment: Oh wow!!! Yea, I guess so @u_mulder. I just noticed it.

Comment: The spaces around #C3 make no difference.  That's also how it is in the other jQuery function I referenced.

Comment: Also, I noticed that the `<button>` doesn't have a `type` property. It might refresh the page. Do you wanna add a `return false;` at the end, making it `onclick="ShowCenter(1); ShowFarRight(150); return false;"`?

Comment: Type is just the name of the input variable -- it doesn't refer to datatype.  I'll add return false.

Comment: @RTC222 I meant `<button type="button">`, not your variable type.

Comment: type="button" not needed.  I have a dozen buttons on the page that use this and they have worked for a long time.  I tried it and it makes no difference.

Comment: where is **ShowCenter**?

Comment: just try first with `  function ShowFarRight(type) {
  console.log("b");

  }
    function ShowCenter(type) {
  console.log("a");
}`

Comment: Is ShowCenter function complete their task?  May be this function refresh your page. So it not give chance to execute the other function

Comment: I just edited the code to add the function ShowCenter.

Comment: I think, @Mangesh Auti, that you may be right.  Each of these pages has a slight delay in the load to give the appearance of a soft load.  I'll look into that.  You see fadeIn(500) in each of the two functions - I think I need to delay before calling the second function ShowFarRight.

Answer (score 1):

You might not added div with id C2 and C3

Try this
https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=G5YT4BCP4J3J

```
    <script>
        var CurrentPageLoad;
        function ShowFarRight(type) {
            console.log("Far Right-1");
            $(" #C3 ").empty();
            $(" #C3 ").scrollTop();
            var filename = "text_" + type + ".html";
            var filename = 'https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_table_basic&stacked=h'; //remove this line
            console.log(filename);
            $( "#C3" ).hide().load( filename ).fadeIn(500);
            console.log("Far Right-2");
        }

        function ShowCenter(type) {
            $(" #C2 ").empty();
            $(" #C2 ").scrollTop();
            var filename = "text_" + type + ".html";
            var filename = 'https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_table_basic&stacked=h'; //remove this line
            $( "#C2" ).hide().load( filename ).fadeIn(500);
            CurrentPageLoad = type;
            console.log("CPL " + CurrentPageLoad);
        }
    </script>
    <div class="C1"><button class="button_01" id="first" onclick="ShowCenter(1); ShowFarRight(150);">Button Text Here</button></div>
    <div id="C2"></div>
    <div id="C3"></div>
```

Comment: You should add some information about the code and how it answer OP question.

Comment: You might not added div with id C2 and C3
    <div id="C2"></div>
    <div id="C3"></div>

Answer (score 0):

This problem occurred because, as @Mangesh Auti said, the first function had not finished before the second one was called because of fadeIn(500).  This can be handled with callbacks, but I did something simpler because the issue is only on this one button out of 12.  I revised the function ShowFarRight to include both sets of code.  When the first is finished, the second starts, and it works.  I no longer call ShowCenter from a click of this particular button.

```
<script>
function ShowFarRight(type) {
  console.log("Far Right");
  $(" #C2 ").empty();
  $(" #C2 ").scrollTop();
  var filename = "text_1.htm"
  $( "#C2" ).hide().load( filename ).fadeIn(500);
  /*___________________________________*/
  $("#C3").empty();
  $("#C3").scrollTop();
  var filename = "text_" + type + ".htm"
  $("#C3").hide().load( filename ).fadeIn(500);
  console.log("Far Right");  }
</script>
```

Now both functions execute, one after the other.